# How to use IConverterSession in pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32, win32com, mapi

pywin32 has an outlook interface called "IConverterSession" which has a method MIMEToMAPI which imports eml files.  Can anyone provide an example of how to access the "IConverterSession" outlook interface and the MINEToMAPI method?

I am using pywin32 build 224 with python3.6.5.  If it helps, the following code does work to open an existing msg file, parse it, and print the sent tag.  It of course spawns outlook in the process.

```
import win32com.client
import win32com.mapi.mapitags

file = r"C:\Path_to_File\test.msg"

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)

print (msg.SentOn)
```

I am referencing the [build comments](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32comext/mapi/src/PyIConverterSession.i) which state:

### Since build 218:

- win32com.mapi
  Added outlook interface IConverterSession with methods MIMEToMAPI,
  MAPIToMIMEStm, and SetAdrBook.

It seems like it would not be too complicated, if only one could find how to access the method "MIMEToMAPI".

Eventually, I would like to use this function to read eml files and save them as msg files.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Extended MAPI:

```
from win32com.mapi import mapi
from win32com.mapi import mapitags
import pythoncom
from win32com import storagecon

mapi.MAPIInitialize((mapi.MAPI_INIT_VERSION, mapi.MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATIONS))

inf = mapi.OpenStreamOnFile('test.eml')
stg = pythoncom.StgCreateDocfile('test.msg',
    storagecon.STGM_CREATE | storagecon.STGM_READWRITE | storagecon.STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE)
msg = mapi.OpenIMsgOnIStg(0, None, stg, None, 0, mapi.MAPI_UNICODE)
cs = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
    mapi.CLSID_IConverterSession, None, pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    mapi.IID_IConverterSession)
cs.MIMEToMAPI(inf, msg, 0)
msg.SaveChanges(0)

mapi.MAPIUninitialize()
```

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar!  The above code worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

[IConverterSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/iconvertersessioniunknown) is IUnknown based, not IDispatch, plus it works with interfaces that I don't think Python understands, such as [IStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istream) and [IMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imessageimapiprop).

You can e[asily parse MIME messages in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html), why not do that and explicitly set various properties on an Outlook message?

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) - it is IDispatch based, so it can easily be used from python. You can create an instance of the [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, call `RDOsession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile` (returns [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object), call `RDOMail.Import( ..., 1024)` followed by `RDOMail.Save`. Its MIME import uses IConverterSession if Outlook is installed or its own MIME parser if it is not.

Comment: Unfortunately, Redemption is not an option.  Surely there is a way to use  IConverterSession / MIMEToMAPI within pywin32 as stated in the build notes.  It would not make much sense to add it to pywin32 otherwise.